# Log each action by tester with KIF

Tags: swift, automated-tests, kif

Using `XCode 6.1`, `Swift` and `KIF 3.1`

Is there any way to log each action for `KIFUITestActor` like tapViewWith... or waitForView....
to see in the terminal not only where it not succeed but where it succeed?